# lubuntu live session in installation ISO

Tags: lubuntu

I want to switch from windows to lubuntu but, before installing lubuntu, I would like to test it on my laptop.

Is there a live session on lubuntu installation ISO so I can test it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there a live session on lubuntu installation ISO so I can test it ?

Yes. If you have an ISO image for Ubuntu or any of its official derivatives, and if `-desktop-` appears in its filename (e.g., `lubuntu-14.04.1-desktop-amd64.iso`), this means it is a live ISO image that contains:

- a usable live desktop interface, with which you can test and otherwise use the OS without installing, *and*
- a utility called Ubiquity (better known as "Install Ubuntu" or, in this case, "Install Lubuntu") that will, when run, provide an interactive, graphical installation of the OS.

When you boot the CD/DVD/USB created from the ISO image, you're asked if you want to try or install the OS. If you select to install it, Ubiquity will run immediately. If you select to try it, you'll get a functioning live desktop, and you can either run Ubiquity or not after that.

The live desktop of an official Ubuntu derivative contains the programs that are installed by default in that derivative. This always includes a web browser, word processor, and various other applications.

Answer (score 0):

If you have already created bootable CD or Flash drive, just pop it in and adjust the boot order in the BIOS.  You will be asked if you want to install Lubuntu or try it out.  Choose try it.  That will not make any changes to your laptop, but you will be able to see if everything works; WIFI,all the programs, etc.