# Booting with 0 bytes HD space

Tags: boot, hard-drive, disk-usage

Can ubuntu boot with 0 bytes HD space?

I was making a backup.
It consumed my whole internal HD (stupid definitely)

I used nautilus to delete the protected folder.

There was nothing in either rubbish bin.

I used the command sync but to no avail.

Everything was running as smoothly as usual. I decided to reboot.

After reboot it refused to boot with external HDs connected. I think this connected to a previous issue. It was resolved here:

https://www.linuxquestions.org/quest...de-4175716928/

External HDs were disconnected and after boot these messages were outputted.

https://postimg.cc/dL0pkddw

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I free up disk space?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/5980/how-do-i-free-up-disk-space) and [lubuntu live session in installation ISO](https://askubuntu.com/q/532658/) The Ubuntu kernel is still installed, but you have 0% avaialable disk space on the hard drive, so you need to free up disk space from an Ubuntu USB live session.

Comment: The simple answer is no. No disk space no boot.